# import database connection file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, database-connection

I can't manage to connect to an SQL database using an external connection file

I am getting an error which is something like `namespace or type specified in the imports 'Pirelli.dbPirelli' does not contain any public member`

Any idea how I can do this??

Thanks!!

Default.aspx.vb

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Common.DbDataReader
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.IO
Imports Pirelli.dbPirelli


Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim SQLdr As SqlDataReader        'The Local Data Store

        cmd.Connection = dbConnectDBOStr


    End Sub
```

**dbPirelli.vb - database connection file:**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Namespace Pirelli


        Public Class dbPirelli
            Public Const strServerName As String = "testserver"  'DEV

            Public Const dbConnectDBOStr As String = "uid=[MYIDHERE];password=[MYPASSHERE];database=[DBNAMEHERE];server=" & strServerName & ";Connection Timeout=60;"

        End Class

    End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference it in this way

```
Imports YourProjectName.Pirelli.dbPirelli
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but do you mean the folder name? I haven't selected a project name

Comment: I meant the application name. It almost always match the folder name. It is the root item at your Solution Explorer